# Number of antennas inside an iPhone 7

Tags: 4g, iphone

I would like to know how many antennas are inside an iPhone 7 for the 4G connection?

Is it possible to have multiple antennas on an iPhone to make the received signal stronger and give better data throughput?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Theres nothing you can do to improve significantly the signal, as the iPhone doesn't support hardware or software upgrades that can improve this side of things.

Here's an example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOuYASBuWJc

Comment: @I870365 how many antennas are inside an iPhone 7 for the 4G connection?